# MS Access currentdb.excute has different result than Docmd.RunSQL

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I use VBA to run an INSERT INTO ... SELECT... SQL query with Currentdb.Execute command. However, I have trouble with the result. There are some rows missing the data.

The result is correct when using Docmd.RunSQL with the same SQL, but I don't want the warning message for inserting data into the table.

I also tried using only the SELECT... with Currentdb.Execute and print the result on the debug window. The result is correct, no missing data.

Here's my code:

```
strsql = strsql & "INSERT INTO tempLineItems (OrderNo, PositionNo, PartNo, [Description], PlannedDeliveryDate, Qty, Unit, Price, Curr, txta, LineItemText, Discount, Tax) "
strsql = strsql & "SELECT dbo_ttdsls041600.t_orno, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_pono, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_item, IIF(dbo_ttipcs021600.t_dsca is null,dbo_ttiitm001600.t_dsca,dbo_ttipcs021600.t_dsca) AS t_dsca, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_ddta, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_oqua, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_cups, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_pric, dbo_ttdsls040600.t_ccur, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_txta, Null AS LineItemText, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_disc_1, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_cvat "
strsql = strsql & "FROM dbo_ttdsls040600 INNER JOIN ((dbo_ttipcs021600 RIGHT JOIN dbo_ttdsls041600 ON (dbo_ttipcs021600.t_item = dbo_ttdsls041600.t_item) AND (dbo_ttipcs021600.t_cprj = dbo_ttdsls041600.t_cprj)) LEFT JOIN dbo_ttiitm001600 ON dbo_ttdsls041600.t_item = dbo_ttiitm001600.t_item) ON dbo_ttdsls040600.t_orno = dbo_ttdsls041600.t_orno "
strsql = strsql & "WHERE (((dbo_ttdsls041600.t_orno)=" & Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Value & ") AND ((dbo_ttdsls041600.t_pono)>0)) "
strsql = strsql & "ORDER BY dbo_ttdsls041600.t_pono;"
```

The problem is on the

```
IIF(dbo_ttipcs021600.t_dsca is null,dbo_ttiitm001600.t_dsca,dbo_ttipcs021600.t_dsca) AS t_dsca
```

I used ISNULL() function, and it has the same result as using Is Null

3/28/2017 Update:
Those tables are linked tables from the SQL Server. I created local tables based on a subset data of those linked ones, and there's no missing data at all.

Comment: or just use `NZ(dbo_ttipcs021600.t_dsca,dbo_ttiitm001600.t_dsca)` and save a few keystrokes.

Comment: I tried NZ() function, but the result came out the same with missing data.

Comment: Why do you bother to alias t_item, especially with its own name? Record is inserted but you are missing data from the Description field? Any others? Want to provide sample data for testing? I recommend Box.com fileshare site.

Comment: I must do something with the t_item before, and didn't remove it when I change it back. Those tables are linked tables from SQL server, and I will try to create a local table and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: I created local tables based on a subset data of those linked ones, and there's no missing data at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very odd. But I've never had to work much with SQLServer tables. To use RunSQL and not get warnings, turn them off and on.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL ...
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just curious about this problem, so I did a different approach by using multiple layer of queries.

```
strsql = strsql & "INSERT INTO tempLineItems (OrderNo, PositionNo, PartNo, Description, PlannedDeliveryDate, Qty, Unit, Price, Curr, txta, LineItemText, Discount, Tax) "
strsql = strsql & "SELECT SO1.t_orno, SO1.t_pono, SO1.t_item, nz(SO1.t_dsca, dbo_ttiitm001600.t_dsca) AS t_dsca, SO1.t_ddta, SO1.t_oqua, SO1.t_cups, SO1.t_pric, SO1.t_ccur, SO1.t_txta, Null AS LineItemText, SO1.t_disc_1, SO1.t_cvat "
strsql = strsql & "FROM (SELECT SO.t_orno, SO.t_ccur, SO.t_pono, SO.t_item, SO.t_oqua, SO.t_pric, SO.t_cups, SO.t_ddta, SO.t_txta, SO.t_disc_1, SO.t_cvat, dbo_ttipcs021600.t_dsca "
strsql = strsql & "FROM (SELECT dbo_ttdsls040600.t_orno, dbo_ttdsls040600.t_ccur, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_pono, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_item, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_pric, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_cups, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_ddta, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_cprj, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_txta, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_disc_1, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_cvat, dbo_ttdsls041600.t_oqua "
strsql = strsql & "FROM dbo_ttdsls041600 INNER JOIN dbo_ttdsls040600 ON dbo_ttdsls041600.t_orno = dbo_ttdsls040600.t_orno "
strsql = strsql & "WHERE (((dbo_ttdsls040600.t_orno)=" & Me.txtSalesOrderNo & "))) SO "
strsql = strsql & "LEFT JOIN dbo_ttipcs021600 ON dbo_ttipcs021600.t_cprj = SO.t_cprj AND dbo_ttipcs021600.t_item = SO.t_item)  AS SO1 LEFT JOIN dbo_ttiitm001600 ON dbo_ttiitm001600.t_item = SO1.t_item "
strsql = strsql & "ORDER BY SO1.t_pono;"
```

And this works!! I guess there's some issue in Access internally.